# How to get a values using scalar function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I hava a column in database table that contains data like

`(102-sled,105-fed,106-gov,107,edu)`

and i want a result like

```
(102,105,106,107) just i want to skip some values
```

Comment: Do you want to extract just numbers from your column ??

Comment: in database its like(102-sled,105-fed,106-gov,107,edu) but i want to result in (102,105,106,107) so all values skip values after '-' until comma

Comment: or just wait a bit.. someone will solve this for you.

Comment: @farhanamjad have a look bro, and do you know why your question is getting so many down votes :), when you ask a question always show what you have tried so far, and describe your problem that what you have and what you exactly want rather then this is what I have ***** a this is what i want **** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNumbers
 (@string varchar(1000))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
 AS
 BEGIN


    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string) <> 0
     BEGIN
      SET @string = STUFF(@string,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string),1,'')
     END

   RETURN   @string;
 END

DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000)
SET @string = 'sk123;fja4567afj;as890'


SELECT dbo.GetNumbers(@string)
```

**Result**

```
1234567890
```

**Edit**

try something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT, Value VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
(1,'102-sled'),(1,'105-fed'),(1,'106-gov'),(1,'107'),(1,'edu')

SELECT DISTINCT ID , STUFF(Q.List, 1, 2, '') NumberList
FROM #temp t CROSS APPLY(
                    SELECT ', '+ dbo.GetNumbers(Value) [text()]
                    FROM #temp 
                    WHERE #temp.ID = t.ID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ) Q(List)
```

**Result**

```
ID  NumberList
1   102, 105, 106, 107,
```

Comment: it is working but i want a result with seperate values with comma e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: @farhanamjad For that you will need to use CROSS APPLY with this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION NUM (@T VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @I TINYINT=1
DECLARE @R VARCHAR(20)=NULL
WHILE @I<=LEN(@T)
BEGIN
IF (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@T,@I,1))>=48 AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(@T,@I,1))<=57)
BEGIN
SET @R=CONCAT(@R,SUBSTRING(@T,@I,1))
END
SET @I+=1
END
RETURN @R
END
```

Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(I VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #T
SELECT '105-fed'
UNION ALL
SELECT '102-sled'
UNION ALL
SELECT '106-gov'
UNION ALL
SELECT '107'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EDU'
SELECT dbo.NUM(I)
FROM #T
WHERE dbo.NUM(I) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #T
```

Result :

(4 row(s) affected)

---

105
102
106
107
(4 row(s) affected)